# Debugging VS2008 project with url other than localhost

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In my host file I have provided this option 
*127.0.0.1       localhost mysite.com* 
so that I can access my localhost site with my custom name (I can access the site directly via typing http://mysite.com/ in browser). Now issue comes how do I do the same with my VS2008. I want to debug my application with url in the browser like this http://mysite.com/ . I tried by putting the "http://mysite.com/ " in *Use Local IIS web server* option textbox of my webproject properties build option but I can't run my project with that. Is this compulsory that I have to enter localhost url only in that textbox. Can you help me in fixing the above issue?

Comment: Are you using the webserver built into visual studio, IIS 7.5 Express, or IIS built into windows?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file HOSTS on C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc.

Like this...

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       my.domain.com
```

Now, on your browser, call http://my.domain.com/APPLICATION

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have already told "In my host file I have provided this option 127.0.0.1 localhost mysite.com"

Comment: Oh...sorry...is there a problem if you change the project properties, on Web tab, to Use Local IIS Web server?

Comment: The issue is not opening it simply in browser. I need to debug the same via my VS.

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually have a site set up in IIS with host name pointed to your site's url: mysite.com. Then go to project options, Web tab and select Use locakl IIS Web server, specifying Project URL as http://mysite.com

Comment: I tried by putting the "http://mysite.com/ " in Use Local IIS web server option textbox of my webproject properties build option but I can't run my project with that. Can you let me know where do I have to put that URL?

Comment: You have to first create new site under IIS, use All Unassigned IP addresses, specify the host name, make sure site is accessible in browser and then make the change to the project. Also make sure Web Site's App Pool is running the same framework as the project is targetting

Comment: I did all what you are saying, I am able to run the site via browser directly. I want to debug it now and if I put "http://mysite.com/ " in my Use Local IIS web server option of VS it is not working  but if I write "http://localhost/ " it is working. May I know can't I put the site name and debug it?

Comment: Yes you can. I actually am doing that right now. Have a website running in IIS and i use the same website url in my project to run it on that URL. if IIS website is configured with www.mysite.com and you put http://mysite.com in VS it will not work. You have to match URL as is in IIS, VS and hosts file...

Comment: Also could you please tell me what do you mean it's not running: Does VS save settings when changed to local IIS? or does it tell you to first set up the virtual directory for the domain name? if it saves, that means VS can access IIS website. Then when you hit F5 does VS load up a page with not found exception?

Comment: Dimitri, thanks for the responses if put "http://mysite.com/" in that textbox it says "Unable to create a virtual directory. Could not find the server "http://mysite.com/" on the local machine". Am I doing right by putting that in "Use Local IIS Web server" textbox ?

Comment: Yes. That means VS cannot communicate with IIS. Is it on the same machine? Also make sure you put full URL in VS properties http: //mysite.com and make sure iis host name points to mysite.com. Both of these have to be exactly similar, meaning if you use www in one, you have to use www in other. and hosts file should also use www

Comment: No success! can you tell a simple procedure to debug an application with url in browser like http://mysite.com

Comment: The simple procedure is described above. If it did not work, there must be something more complex